# Check if record exists Before Insertion using laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to check record is_featured is a column name if any product is is_featured 1 is already exist error message should be shown **Trying to assign an already assigned featured**
how can i do that please help me thanks.

https://ibb.co/1Zv2KBW

**controller**

```
public function featured(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->id) {
            $featured = $request->input('is_featured');
            $assignFeature = Product::where('is_featured', '=', $featured)->first();
            if ($assignFeature) {
                abort(405, 'Trying to assign an already assigned featured');
            }
        } else {
            $response['is_featured'] = false;
            $response['message'] = 'Oops! Something went wrong.';

            $id = $request->input('id');
            $featured = $request->input('is_featured');

            $featureditem = Product::find($id);

            if ($featureditem->update(['is_featured' => $featured])) {

                // form helpers.php
                logAction($request);

                $response['is_featured'] = true;
                $response['message'] = 'product featured updated successfully.';
                return response()->json($response, 200);
            }
            return response()->json($response, 409);
        }
    }
```

**ajax script**

```
        $('.postfeatured').change(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var id = $this.val();
            var is_featured = this.checked;
            
            if (is_featured) {
              is_featured = 1;
            } else {
              is_featured = 0;
            }
        
            axios
              .post('{{route("product.featured")}}', {
                _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
                _method: 'patch',
                id: id,
                is_featured: is_featured,
              })
              .then(function (responsive) {
                console.log(responsive);

              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
          });
```

Comment: What error  you r getting .?

Comment: please put the error message in your question.. without it, we don't know what is your problem.. Thankyou

Comment: @ZubairMukhtar this error is handel by you in this code i think u can change it right .?

Comment: please check error you can better understand   https://ibb.co/Lpt71jv

Comment: @ZubairMukhtar `abort(405, 'Trying to assign an already assigned featured');` this is you throwing this error

Comment: when enabled to any checkbox before it should be checked if in feature column 1 is already exist so checkbox should be disable thanks.

Comment: @ZubairMukhtar please read code all is there

Comment: this query is not working propely .   
$assignFeature = Product::where('is_featured', '=', $featured)->first();

Answer (score 1):

remove this `abort()`

```php
 if ($assignFeature) {
        //abort(405, 'Trying to assign an already assigned featured'); //remove this
        $response['is_featured'] = false;
        $response['message'] = 'Trying to assign an already assigned featured.';
        return response()->json($response, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $product_created_status = $product->wasRecentlyCreated ? 1 : 0 ;
```

if product is already created it returns 0, else returns 1

Comment: when enabled to any checkbox before it should be checked if in feature column 1 is already exist so checkbox should be disable thanks.